# facebook publish_action not supported?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm a bit confused. I've read the docs and tutorials on the web for getting permission for "publish_action" so that the user can choose the option to automatically post a link on their FB feed when they create a new post on my site (instead of having to do it manually every time).

I set up the page to obtain the user permission for "publish_action" and created the parameters (as shown below). THis works great when I do it, but I am using my developer account. On the facebook developer group I was informed that we are not able to write the message, caption, or link description for the user.

Is this really the case? If so, how is that different than the share dialogue? What's the point in the publish_action permission? Is the publish_action deprecated?

```
$params = array(
                      "message" => "I just added a new post.",
                      "link" => $post_link,
                      "picture" => "http://example.com/fbpreview2.jpg",
                      "name" => "Name of website",
                      "caption" => "www.example.com"
                      , "description" => "This is a website"
                    );
$request = ( new FacebookRequest( $session, 'POST', '/me/feed', $params ) )->execute()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook [Platform Policy's documentation on prefilling](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/prefill) requires that the user have typed everything in the `message` parameter.

If you post only the contents of the user-generated post, you should be compliant with the rules. Adding anything to it that the user didn't explicitly type - additional copy, links, hashtags, etc. - is forbidden.

As an example, if I posted a blog post to a blogging system, you could provide a "post this to Facebook too" checkbox/button. Posting the blog entry's exact user-typed text would be OK, but posting a message like "I just blogged on example.com/post.html" would be forbidden.

`/me/feed` [doesn't accept](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/feed#publish) `caption` or `description` parameters, so it won't matter if you pre-fill them - they don't do anything.